# SQL SUM not SUM Specific Column

Tags: sql, oracle

How to SUM my column (Q.QTY) in my table using database oracle ?
The SQL code like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT
M.MODEL_NO,
P.FORM_NO,
P.MODEL_NO,
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(P.DATE_ADDED,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MONTH'),
Q.FORM_NO,
Q.STATUS_QTY,
SUM(Q.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY P.FORM_NO ORDER BY P.FORM_NO
RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) QTY

FROM
SEIAPPS_MODEL M, SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P, SEIAPPS_QTY Q

WHERE
P.FORM_NO = Q.FORM_NO AND P.MODEL_NO = M.MODEL_NO AND M.MODEL_NO = '15' AND P.DATE_ADDED LIKE '2013-05%' AND Q.STATUS_QTY = 'OK';
```

When I query this SQL code in TOAD, it will show all data, not SUM for all in Q.QTY column.

What I wanted is like this :

```
QTY
5000 (example value)
```

Please advice. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The simplest is to use your query as a derived table and add the sums of all columns:

```
SELECT SUM(MODEL_NO1) + SUM(FORM_NO1) + SUM(MODEL_NO2) + SUM(TOCHAR) + 
    SUM(FORM_NO2) + SUM(STATUS_QTY) + SUM(QTY) AS SUM_ALL
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
    M.MODEL_NO AS MODEL_NO1,
    P.FORM_NO AS FORM_NO1,
    P.MODEL_NO AS MODEL_NO2,
    TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(P.DATE_ADDED,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MONTH') AS TOCHAR,
    Q.FORM_NO AS FORM_NO2,
    Q.STATUS_QTY,
    SUM(Q.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY P.FORM_NO ORDER BY P.FORM_NO
    RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) QTY

    FROM
    SEIAPPS_MODEL M, SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P, SEIAPPS_QTY Q

    WHERE
    P.FORM_NO = Q.FORM_NO AND P.MODEL_NO = M.MODEL_NO AND M.MODEL_NO = '15' AND P.DATE_ADDED LIKE '2013-05%' AND Q.STATUS_QTY = 'OK'
) x
```

Note you have ambiguous column names and unnamed columns so I have had to give them an alias.

Comment: How about continue in my code ? actually for SUM_ALL just example... I need to SUM all of column in SUM(Q.QTY).. Thanks

Comment: @AseanJazz I'm sorry, I don't follow

Comment: It's ok, so any advice ?

Comment: @AseanJazz I can't give you any advice because I don't understand what you're asking.

Comment: Sorry, I've updated my question. Please take a time to read it again. :)

Answer (score 0):

I looks like you want the total for all of Q.QTY.  You're using a window function.  More info here.

http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/functions004.htm#i81407

Also, I recommend using ANSI join syntax instead.

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
M.MODEL_NO,
P.FORM_NO,
P.MODEL_NO,
TO_CHAR(TO_DATE(P.DATE_ADDED,'YYYY-MM-DD'),'MONTH'),
Q.FORM_NO,
Q.STATUS_QTY,
SUM(Q.QTY) OVER (PARTITION BY P.FORM_NO ORDER BY P.FORM_NO
RANGE UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) QTY
SUM(Q.QTY) OVER() As SumOfAll -- Sum of the entire QTY column
FROM SEIAPPS_MODEL M
JOIN SEIAPPS_PRODUCTION_STATUS P
  ON P.MODEL_NO = M.MODEL_NO
JOIN SEIAPPS_QTY Q
  ON P.FORM_NO = Q.FORM_NO
WHERE
  M.MODEL_NO = '15' AND P.DATE_ADDED LIKE '2013-05%' AND Q.STATUS_QTY = 'OK';
```